# Eloquent Nested relations with where clause query returns collection on false condition

Tags: php, laravel, collections, subquery

I am trying to search for all Rents that have a RentItem with a book title LIKE the given $input.

The problem is when the input does not match,I still get a collection returned.
The only difference is that the book relation is null instead of a collection.

Result of query that should return false:
https://pastebin.com/pd7UqhCi

Result of query that is true:
https://pastebin.com/shndvdMh

When book equals null, I do not want the Rent model to be returned.

My query

```
$rents = Rent::with(['rentItems.book' => function ($query) use ($input) { 
       $query->where('books.title', 'LIKE', "%$input%"); 
}])->get();
```

Rent model Relation

```
public function rentItems()
{
  return $this->hasMany(RentItem::class);
}
```

RentItems model Relations

```
public function book()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}

public function rent()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(Rent::class);
}
```

Research i have done:

- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/eloquent-nested-relations-with-where-clause
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/using-wherehas-and-with
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Answer (score 14):

You need to use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method. Do something like this:

```
$rents = Rent::whereHas('rentItems.book', function ($query) use ($input) { 
    $query->where('books.title', 'LIKE', "%$input%"); 
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm.

Comment: Why not add a "with('rentItems.book')", this does not eager load. Actually not sure if op wants that

Comment: OP doesn't want to eager load. He wants to filter `Rent` records by relationship.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin can you help me if there's any error in this below query.
Attendance::with(['teacher:EMPID,EMPNAME,EMAIL,MOBILENO,SCHOOLID,DESIGNATION', 'classs:SID,CLASSNAME,SCHOOLID', 'attendanceAbsent.student', 'attendanceAbsent.leave'])->whereDate('created_at', $request->date)->whereHas("attendanceAbsent", function($q) use($request) {
                        $q->where("attendance_id", "=", $request->id);
                    })->whereHas('attendanceAbsent.leave', function ($query) {
                        $query->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today());
                    })->first()